# Show loader while dynamic content is being populated in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using the following snippet :

```
function fetchContent()
{
    //do something
    $.mobile.changePage("#toTheTargetPage");
}

$("#toTheTargetPage").live('pagebeforeshow', function() {    
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Please wait", false); 
    renderTheContent();  
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});

function renderTheContent()
{
    //populate dynamic list view using the content
}
```

But it doesn't show the loader. And it also doesn't show the listview on the first load. If I go back and return again, only then is the content being shown.

Where am I going wrong?

Note : Using jquery Mobile 1.2.0

Comment: are you using an ajax call to render dynamic content?

Comment: @hungerpain no. AJAX call to fetchContent. And then I store it locally, and use that in renderTheContent.

Comment: okay.. it might be helpful if you show us the renderContent() code

Comment: and one more - what jQuery version are u using?

Comment: @hungerpain jQuery version is 1.8.2 and inside renderContent() I'm making a dynamic list view.

Comment: try changing the `pagebeforeshow` to `pageinit`. and see if you get the data onload

Comment: @hungerpain No. `pageinit` won't work. Because it'll only be called once. Whereas my AJAX calls can be made many times, so I'll need to use some event for page render, not page initialisation. And I did test. It didn't work.

Comment: you dint mention your `ajax`calls will be called multiple times :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33029/discussion-between-hungerpain-and-kazekage-gaara)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues you had with your code :

- In your `each` method, you were refreshing your `listview` after every single row. Which isnt advised. I changed that to make `each` push the HTML into an array, which u could push into the `listview`.

  ```
  var li = [];
  $.each(doctors, function (obj, doctor) {
      //console.log(doctor.DoctorRating);
      ratingHtml = populateRatingDiv(doctor.DoctorRating);
      //console.log(obj);
      li.push("<li data-role='list-divider'>" + toTitleCase(doctor.DoctorName) + "<div class='ratings'>" + ratingHtml + "</div></li>" + "<li data-icon='false'><a data-doc=" + obj + " onclick='showDocDetails(this);'><img src='images/doctor.png' style='margin-top:5%'/><div><h3>" + doctor.DoctorSpecialisation + "</h3><p><strong>Phone : " + doctor.DoctorPhone + "</strong></p><p>" + doctor.DoctorAddress + "</p></div></a></li>");
  });
  $("#doctorListView").append(li);
  ```
- Removed all the `live` methods and converted it to `on`. `live` was removed in v1.9 and `on` replaced it. Even though you use an older version, it would do good to benefit from `on`.
- Changed your `pagebeforeshow` event to `pageshow`. For some reason its not working on 1.2 the way it should. And added a `pagehide` method which will clear the HTML of `ul` so that it won't be seen the next time `pageshow` happens.

  ```
  $(document).on({
   'pageshow': function (e) {
      populateDoctorList();
    },
    'pagehide': function () {
      $(this).find("ul").html("");
    }
  }, "#doctorList");
  ```
- Moved the `loading` show and hide methods to `populateDoctorList`. The context must be the same for the action you're currently doing and the loading methods. Else it wont work.

  ```
  function populateDoctorList() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Please wait", false);
    //rest if your code 
  }
  ```
- To hide the `loading` you must wait till the listview is ready to be used. Hence, added a `promise()` to the `append` and then called the hide of loading. `promise` ensures that everything is completed so applying the `loading("hide")` here makes sense.

  ```
  $ul.append(li).promise().done(function () {
      $(this).attr("data-role", "listview").listview().listview("refresh");
      $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
  });
  ```
- a prototype - http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/kgWym/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. :-)